# Method signature refactor to const in CLion

Tags: c++, clion

I am using intellij clion for c++ program.
I am using with method signature refactor (ctrl+F6).
How I can change signature from non const method, to const?

[Link](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/change-signature.html?utm_content=2016.3&utm_medium=help_link&utm_source=from_product&utm_campaign=CL) to understand.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, adding/removing CV-qualifiers during Change Signature refactoring is not yet implemented in CLion, please follow or upvote the corresponding [issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/CPP-1998).

Answer (score 0):

So far easiest way is to replace string throughout the project (Edit->Find->Replace in path):

```
"<method name>(<parameters>) <existing attributes set>"
```

with

```
"<method name>(<parameters>) <new attributes set>"
```

E.g.:

```
replace what: "initImpl(GraphicsContext *context)"
replace with: "initImpl(GraphicsContext *context) const"
```

This will replace:

- method declaration
- overrides declarations in child classes
- all method definitions.

Well, that won't work for places where you use different type synonyms.

Cheers!

[image]
[image]